# Sitecore faceting on phrases using SOLR

Tags: solr, sitecore, facet, faceted-search

Does anyone have an example of the sitecore index configuration while using SOLR, for keyword tokenizer?
I am trying to facet on a field which has multiword strings, but the facets currently being returned are splitting the words in the fields and returning facets.

Eg. I have items with a field for state, and i am trying to facet on the state field - which has values like New Hampshire, South Dakota. 
But in the results, I get facet values with 
Name = New, Aggregate = xx
Name = Hampshire, Aggregate = xx
Name = South, Aggregate = xx
Name = Dakota, Aggregate = xx

Could anyone please help me with the right configuration to change this?

This is my current configuration:

```xml
      <index id="site_search_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="core">site_search_web</param>
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
        </strategies>

        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/Home</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
      </index>
```

Comment: You should be able to change the type of the field to be string instead of using a text type with a tokenizer. Tokenizers break the text on token boundaries like space, hyphen, etc., which is why you are seeing the individual tokens in the facets.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this on an index level instead of field level? I would really appreciate sample config in that case! Thanks!

Comment: I believe you're locked to the field level, but you can always use a computed field or declare an alias to that field with a different datatype and use that instead for any special cases.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by one of the following solutions:

***Solution 1***

You can create a computed field that returns the facet value and set the computed field type to "string" to avoid tokenization.
Your computed field should look like:

```cs
public class TitleComputedField : IComputedIndexField
{
    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        if (indexable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("indexable");
        var scIndexable = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (scIndexable == null)
        {
            Log.Warn(
                this + " : unsupported IIndexable type : " + indexable.GetType(), this);
            return false;
        }

        var item = (Item)scIndexable;
        if (item == null)
        {
            Log.Warn(
                this + " : unsupported SitecoreIndexableItem type : " + scIndexable.GetType(), this);
            return false;
        }

        if (String.Compare(item.Database.Name, "core", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return = item.Fields["Title"];
    }

    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }
}
```

And configure the computed field in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Indexes.config as follows:

```xml
      <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
        ...
        <field fieldName="plaintitle"             returnType="string">YourNamespace.TitleComputedField, YourAssembly</field>
      </fields>
```

And finally if you facet on the "plaintitle" field, you should get the expected results.

***Solution 2***

You can create the field on the index level by updating the solr schema.xml as follows:

Create a new field in solr of type  string

```xml
<fields>
   ...
   <field name="plaintitle" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</fields>
```

and then create a "copyfield" to copy the original field into the new one

```xml
<copyField source="title_t" dest="plaintitle" />
```

in both solutions you can facet on the new field using the following code:

```cs
query.FacetOn(i => i["plaintitle"]);
```